# Insert VBA code to existing xlsm file using C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba, epplus

I have been trying to find a solution for this issue for a few days and got no where so I'd appreciate if some can direct me on this. I have a piece of code that is using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace
but I have to convert this code using EPplus lib because on our server we only have this lib available
here is the code , it added VBA code from string to specific sheet (2)

```
        string VBCode = VBACode.GetVbCode();//vba code
      
        Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.VBProject Project = Workbook.VBProject;
        Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.VBComponent Module = Workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Item(2);//sheet2
       
        Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.CodeModule Code = Module.CodeModule;
        Code.AddFromString(VBCode);
```

I tried this code but it adds the vba code to ThisWoorkBook module not the sheet
Thanks in advance
//openxml EPPlus
using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(fileName), true))
{

```
            pck.Workbook.CreateVBAProject();
            pck.Workbook.Worksheets[2].Workbook.CodeModule.Code = VBACode.GetVbCode();
```

Comment: Try `Workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Item(Workbook.Worksheets(2).CodeName)` instead of `Workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Item(2)`

Comment: Hi Siddharth, this works when we use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll but I cannot use ithis. I should be using EPPlus